# Data is incorrectly grouped by days from timestamp with the specified time zone offset

Tags: postgresql

My database stores data with time stamps in UTC-0 in integer format. On the web server, it is necessary to calculate how much data is stored in each day, taking into account the user's time zone.

Example of grouping:

```
...group by extract(epoch from date_trunc('hours', to_timestamp(timestamp_integer) at time zone '+5'));
```

+5 - user's time zone

```
select extract(epoch from date_trunc('hours', to_timestamp(1670958457) at time zone '+5'));
```

For example, I took a timestamp, but it resets a day ago, and not before the beginning of the day of this timestamp in the specified time zone

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem this way. A positive UTC value is set west of Greenwich

```
select extract(epoch from date_trunc('days', to_timestamp(1670958457), 'UTC-05'));
```